Page Transition Python Code not working. No Clue Why
Context: Need to Create code to check for package size and that about it
Issue: I made a menu to change between pages, and it isn't changing, constantly repeating the package checking page.
# Set A whole lot of variable
letter = ''
next_page = ''
main_page = 1
check_page = 0
history_page = 0

# IBM Interface Style
print(":/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\：")
print(":| Program: [MAIL] Monitoring and Inspection of Logistic   V.1 |：")
print(":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/：")

print("\n __________________________________________________________ ")
print("|                                                          |")
print("| Welcome to [MAIL], Monitoring and Inspection of Logistic |")
print("|__________________________________________________________|")

# Menu for Program
while main_page == 1:
    print("\nGood day")
    print("\npress\tA... Parcel Checking")
    print("\tB... Parcel History")
    letter = input("\nPress any LETTER key.")

    # Checking again for User input...
    while letter != 'A' and letter != 'B' and letter != 'C':
        print("\nPlease enter only the LETTER shown")
        print("\npress\tA... Parcel Checking")
        print("\tB... Parcel History")
        letter = input("\nPress any LETTER key.")

    # Turn Page on and Off Type
    if letter == 'A':
        check_page = 1
        main_page = 0
            
    if letter == 'B':
        history_page = 1
        main_page = 0

# This is the input/checking page
while check_page == 1:
    print("\n\t\t\tParcel Checking")
    print("Enter the following parameters for checking in (cm)")
    length = input("Length> ")
    while not length.isdigit() or float(length) <= 0 or float(length) > 80:
        if not length.isdigit():
            length = input("False Parameters Detected. Enter LENGTH>") 
        elif float(length) > 80:
            length = input("Parameters Violated. More than 80cm Detected. Enter LENGTH> ")

    width = input("Width> ")
    while not width.isdigit() or float(width) <= 0 or float(width) > 80:
        if not width.isdigit():
            width = input("False Parameters Detected. Enter WIDTH once more.")
        elif float(width) > 80:
            width = input("Parameters Violated. More than 80cm Detected. Enter WIDTH> ")
            
    height = input("Height> ")
    while not height.isdigit() or float(height) <= 0 or float(height) > 80:
        if not height.isdigit():
            height = input("False Parameters Detected. Enter HEIGHT once more.")
        elif float(height) > 80:
            height = input("Parameters Violated. More than 80cm Detected. Enter HEIGHT> ")
    
    weight = input("Weight> ")
    while not weight.isdigit() or float(weight) <= 0:
        if not weight.isdigit():
            weight = input("False Parameters Detected. Enter WEIGHT once more.")
        elif float(height) > 10:
            height = input("Parameters Violated. More than 10Kg. Detected. Enter HEIGHT> ")

    next_package = input("Input Next Package (Y)/(N)")

    while next_package != 'Y' and next_package != 'N':
        print("Please enter only 'Y' or 'N'")
        next_package = input("Input Next Package (Y)/(N) ")

    if next_package == 'N':
        check_page = 0
        main_page = 1



    


Edit: I redid the code, copying only the things I need and removing the unnecessary parts. Other than that the results now produces nothing, basically empty like a "break"

check_page == 1 At the very end of the code you are comparing check_page to 1, you are not assigning.  I think you meant to use only one equal sign here.

I did change it but it would still not work. Only two results appeared, either "Parcel Checking" Would repeat again or the code just stops producing anything

The final if next_package == 'N' statement should not be indented underneath the while next_package != 'Y' and next_package != 'N': loop.  It should be at the same level.

#Replace your code from last loop with this.

#Here you added if-else condition in while loop. and hence it will 
check condition only in the case when O/P other than Y or N is given

while next_package != 'Y' and next_package != 'N':
    print("Please enter only 'Y' or 'N'")
    next_package = input("Input Next Package (Y)/(N)")

if next_package == 'Y':
    check_page = 1
    main_page = 0

elif next_package == 'N':
    check_page = 0
    main_page = 1


I've tried yours. Two issues appear mainly that im seem to be facing.

It repeats the Parcel checking regardless
It just stops working like a break just happen

I inputed your code, the "1." scenario happened, non stop.
I tweaked it a lot, from changing the main_page to a if loop, didnt work
Changed, stuff here and there, either "1." scenario or the "2." happens.
